# Snippets not coming in results in Solr 5.3

Tags: solr

Following is my schema design for content field (I have tried using `type="text"` also).

```xml
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And following is my query.

```sql
q=crime&hl=true&hl.fl=content&hl.requireFieldMatch=true&hl.fragsize=700&
hl.snippets=10&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&facet=true&
facet.field=permauid&facet.field=info_owner&facet.sort=count&
facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=-1&wt=python&sort=score+asc&start=0&
rows=20&fl=uid,permauid
```

In the result, I am not getting the snippets. I am getting "**highlighting**" value of the result as follows:

```
highlighting':{'ANV355-rw%$$%ANV355%$$%1':{},'ANV355-rw%$$%ANV355%$$%2':{},'ANV355-rw%$$%ANV355%$$%3':{}
```